# How to avoid flickering when showing DOM element only on desktop computers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show a DOM element only if the user is using a desktop computer. NOT according to the screen's dimensions; a 1300px wide desktop computer needs to show the element while a 1366px wide iPad must not.

My current solution is the jQuery code below:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if($.browser.mobile) {
            $("#desktop-only").remove();
        }
    });
```

It works, but it implies a flicker of the element `#desktop-only`.

Anything similar like using `/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)` still flickers.

Surely a better solution exist?

Comment: CSS media queries FTW, Why use JavaScript at all for this?

Comment: But those only take screen dimensions in account, don't they?

Comment: Yes. And you are also using a feature that is deprecated in jQuery.

Comment: look into using --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia and by default make the element `display:none` !

Comment: What ever you are going to do with JavaScript is going to flicker because you are either showing or hiding it based on when it is being rendered.

Comment: Very good point. The thing is, I don't want this to be based on the screen dimensions at all, I want it to be based on whether or not the user is using a mobile device. So a very high resolution tablet needs to be out.

Comment: Even a retina iPad in landscape mode will match `@media (max-width: 1024px)`. `width` does not relate to physical pixels. The only iPad exceeding that is the iPad Pro. Afaik there is no reliable method - neither in JS nor in CSS, nor on the server side, to detect a mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the question inspired a solution...

Instead of removing the element from the DOM if the user is on mobile, I set  `display: none;` on the element and then show it if the user is not on mobile.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        if(!$.browser.mobile) {
            $("#subscription-web").css("display", "block");
        }
     });
```

No more flicker on mobile, and the element pops into view on desktop. So it still kinda flickers, but in a much less anoying way.

Any better solution welcome!

Comment: No flicker, now stuff jumps as the content is added in.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant by "kinda flickers" I'm quite satisfied for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery function like .
[show](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_show.asp)() and hide()

```
  $( document ).ready(function() { if(!$.browser.mobile) { $("#subscription-web").show('slow')} }
```

$(selector).show(speed,easing,callback)